# BulletedList onClick not firing

Tags: c#, events, webforms, bulletedlist

Ugh, this is driving me mad

Im trying to build up a dynamic menu from a bulletedList, most menu items are plain links however the log out button needs to perform some cleanup code.

I cant for the life of me get the BullettedLists onclick event to fire.
The BulletedList is inside a user control (if that makes a difference)

Any ideas? 
Or - any ideas for an alternative, better solution?

Code below

BulletedList

```
<asp:BulletedList OnClick="menu_Click" runat="server" CssClass="MainMenu" ID="loggedInMenu" DisplayMode="HyperLink"  />
```

Adding an element

```
loggedInMenu.Items.Add(new ListItem("Logout", ""));
```

Click handler

```
protected void menu_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{

    user.logout();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong `DisplayMode` for your `BulletedList` control.  You should use a `DisplayMode` of `LinkButton`.  When you use `DisplayMode.HyperLink`:

> Users can click links to move to
>   another page. You must provide a
>   target URL as the Value property of
>   individual items.

This is from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228101.aspx) for this control.  (It's about 3/4 of the way down the page.)

When you use a `BulletedList` control in `HyperLink` mode, the value of your `ListItem` is the URL that you're navigating to.  So your static page HTML controls would use `ListItem.Value` as the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag.

Here's what the HTML markup looks like when you use a DisplayMode of HyperLink (it's a plain old HTML anchor tag w/ a href):

```
<li><a href="1">One</a></li>
```

But since you want to postback, you should set the `DisplayMode` of your `BulletedList` control to `LinkButton`.  When you do that, you'll enable a postback back to your page and your event handler will trap the event.  You can then process the click appropriately then.  The event argument that's passed in (of type `BulletedListEventArgs`) will have an `Index` property, and that will tell you what item in your list was clicked.

Here's the updated .aspx code that I used:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="bullet" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton"
    onclick="bullet_Click">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Everything else is the same except the `DisplayMode`, which is set to `LinkButton`.  When I use that, then my `bullet_Click` event handler is fired when I click a list item.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: yup, that did it. Thanks. I'm gonna keep trying to find another more flexible solution, Im not sure I want all these post backs happening on the OTHER links

Comment: What are you trying to do on the postback fir the other links?  You may want to consider some AJAX functionality and potentially use a framework like jQuery. It's very easy to build up a dynamic list and handle events with it.  Let me know and I can add an example.

Comment: hey, Ajax is exactly what I did in the end, still using the bulletedList (with hyperlinks), then I added an onclick attribute to one of the items. The onclick then fired off an ajax call.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Lately I've found that I can avoid a lot of postbacks by using a little client-side functionality.  jQuery (along with a few other frameworks) has opened my eyes to a different world of web programming.  Good luck!